# Convergence multi variable newton method with polynominals

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

I have n polynominals in n variable. Are there any sentences that gurantee convergence if the jacobian is not singular at the start point?

I have one linear polynom in n variables. And n-2 polynominals secound degree in one variable (all of the same form) and one eight degree polynominal in two variables. I know that all zeros lie in the unity cube.

5x + 6y + 7z + 9w + 11a = 55

x^2-x=0
y^2-y=0
z^2-z=0
((1-w)^2+(1-a)^2)*((1-w)^2+a^2)*(w^2+(1-a)^2)*(w^2+a^2) = 0

Answer (score 1):

Why do you not solve the $n-2$ quadratic polynomials in one variable each first. This fixes $n-2$ variables and leaves 2 free. Then insert the linear equation into the 8th degree polynomial to get a univariate polynomial of degree 8. Standard solvers are well capable to treat this degree.

You may want to iterate over all $2^{n-2}$ combinations of the solutions of the quadratic equation, giving $8·2^{n-2}$ of (possibly complex) solutions.

---

You can not trick complexity. Translating discrete problems like SAT or knapsack problems into polynomial equations just gives you polynomial systems that have a high complexity. Generally, if one starts in a region of quadratic convergence, then of course the Newton method will converge to the corresponding solutions. It is the global task of locating all of those regions of quadratic convergence where everything, complexity, condition number, (inverse) size of the basins of quadratic convergence etc. is governed by the total number of complex solutions of the system (and all systems of intermediate steps), independent of the method. If your example system is typical, then the fastest method is to try out all $2^n$ combinations of $0$ and $1$ for the variables.

Comment: no each quadratic polynom yield 2 zeros. They depend on the linear one so you can't fix them. Trying all 2^(n-2) is impossiblr for large n.

Comment: Sorry, don't know how the $8$ slipped into the place of $n-2$. Could you add an example system to your question, for $n=5$ or so, with "invented but typical" coefficients?

Comment: i did it i added it

Comment: i added your information.

Comment: So it is exactly as expected. You can not avoid the complexity of considering all $2^{n-2}$ combinations of the solutions of the univariate quadratic equations. -- Is the last polynomial always factored that way? Then you can split the task from the beginning into subtasks for each factor. Or just use the encoded conditions $x,y,z,w,a\in \{0,1\}$. -- It is generally a bad idea to translate integer programming problems into polynomial problems. Or generally number theory problems like the big Fermat into analytical versions.

Answer (score 0):

There is [Kantorovich theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kantorovich_theorem) which states that Newton's method will converge for a general system when starting point is *sufficiently* close to the solution. That result is pretty hard to apply practically because of need to estimate a uniform bound to jacobian inverse norm.

The case of $n$ polynomials versus $n$ generic functions is not simplier (as far as i know) unless you have some very specific polynomial system. There's also no guarantee that this system would have a solution.

For example, I've attempted to solve some polynomial system arising from numerical quadratures construction. The system had $n = 20$ equations and Newton's method was failing to converge if the starting point was not close to the solution with at least 10 digits of precision.

Comment: I know that it has a solution. I added some information, this might make things easier. Is threre a method with better convergence?